# What is the form of polynomial if we know that $x(t) = x(t + 1)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I have a polynomial, about which I know only the fact, that $\forall t \in \mathbb{C}$ $x(t) = x(t+1)$. This implies, that $x(t+1) = x(t+2)$, also $x(t) = x(t+n)$ generally. Is the polynomial there a zero polynomial $\mathcal{O}(t)$?

Comment: I agree with some of the posters.. The polynomial is either of zero degree or of infinite degree. If of infinite degree, it's not even a polynomial; it's a Taylor Series.

Answer (score 3):

You can only conclude that $x(t)$ is a polynomial with period $1$. And a periodic polynomial can only be a constant which may or may not be $0$.

Comment: I.e. degree 1 polynomial?

Comment: @AcceleratetotheInfinity No, not at all. Period 1, not degree 1.

Comment: I've googled it up, it has to do something with complex analysis, which I never had. This is from my introductory linear algebra class... Is there some way to interpret it in the field of linear algebra?

Comment: A periodic polynomial must be constant, and no complex analysis is requuired.

Answer (score 3):

If $x(t) $ is a polynomial of degree $d>0$, $x(t+1)-x(t)$ is a (non-zero) polynomial of degree $d-1$. Thus $x(t)$ is $0$ or a polynomial of degree $0$, i.e. a constant.

Comment: $x(t)$ cannot have degree 1. Your original argument was correct because the degree of zero polynomial is undefined (or conventionally set to $-\infty$, depending on the definition)!

Comment: @Sangchul Lee. You're right. Today's not my day, and I shouldn't be doing too many things. I fixed my answer, adding a small detail; Note $0$ is sometimes described to be of degree $-1$.

Answer (score 2):

If a polynomial $p(t)$ has this property, then all the polynomials $p(t)-\alpha$ have the same periodic property for any constant $\alpha$ (and they have the same degree as $p(t)$).

Choose, for example, $\alpha=p(1)$.
Then the polynomial $p(t)-p(1)$ has periodic property and so all the positive integers are roots of this polynomial. But a non-constant polynomial cannot have infinitely many roots. So $p(t)-p(1)$ and hence $p(t)$ must be a constant.

Answer (score 1):

The polynomial $y(t) =x(t) - x(0)$ is zero for all $t\in\mathbb{N} $ and by the fundamental theorem of algebra it has to be constant zero. Hence, $x$ is constant.